Fan capacitor replacement 4 wires. same 5uf+5uf but the wires are totally different colors? how to connect
the old capacitor was a SK  4 wires 2greens 2 browns directly connected to the electronic board, (5uf+5uf 250v(Casablanca cottage fan)).this fan has a remote control w2 and a receiver model 780 7150
I could not find the same capacitor and I bought a BM CBB1 5uf 5uf 250v but it has 2 grey wires and 1 brown  1 green.I assume it's a non polarized capacitor.
Should I connect the new one based on the same position of the wires on the old capacitor or should I do something different.
thx for your help

According to the diagram on the capacitors:

The one currently connected, with two green wires and two brown wires, has the capacitors connected separately, i.e., they are not wired together internally.
The grayish replacement appears to have the two gray wires connected together internally, but it is hard to be sure from that photo.

Check with a continuity tester if the two grays are connected. If so, then the second capacitor might, or might not work -- you'd need to see if a green and brown wire pair in the existing capacitors are also connected together, and connect the two gray wires to those two points.
From your comment, confirming that the original capacitors were independent, but the new one is not, the only way you could use that new one is if, on the printed circuit board (PCB) where the old capacitor was connected, two capacitor wires are connected by a PCB trace. If so, then connect the two gray wires to those paired connections, and the other wires, regardless of color, to the other holes that are not connected together.
If there are not two commonly-connected spots on the board, then do not use the new capacitors.
BTW, it's often easier to solder to the copper side of the PCB, since heat of removing the old caps may make the traces ready to peel off the board.
That said, what leads you to believe the existing capacitors are dead? Have you tested them? It's just as likely there's a different cause of an issue.

Thx that's helpful.I just tested the continuity and the the 2 gray wires are connected on the new capacitor.  But on the old capacitor none of the wires are connected.

also, the reason I think the capacitor is damaged is that my fan would stat but run super super slowly making a strange humming noise like the motor got rust in it. I checked the bearings but it did not seem to be that.I could spin the fan manually and it would rotate for 12 seconds  and with no noise.

should I try to connect the new one? or maybe any advise on where to find a 4 wires not connected  capacitor 5uf+5uf?

@user281554, he3 answer has been edited for clarification.
